# Video Player for Splash Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I made the splash screen for my app. But now, I want to use .mp4 extension in splash screen.

How can I do? Please help me.
And, this is my code about splash screen using AssetImage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bankingapp/main.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MySplash()));
}

class MySplash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySplashState createState() => _MySplashState();
}

class _MySplashState extends State<MySplash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyBottomNavigationBar()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image:
                DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/images/splash.jpg"))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `video player` package : https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

Comment: just create a controller and initialized it by following the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for some kind of animation in splash screen, you can use [lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) package. You can use this [site](https://isotropic.co/video-to-lottie/) to convert `mp4` to `lottie.json`

Replace the `container` with this widget

```
Lottie.asset(
  'assets/LottieLogo1.json',
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

Comment: And how is it possible to make a splash screen out of it? I want to display an animation while the app is initialising in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Use this video player [video_player plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) 
& Save your mp4 file in assets/videos location
Try the below code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

import 'HomePage.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  bool _visible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/video/splash_video.mp4");
    _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      _controller.setLooping(true);
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        setState(() {
          _controller.play();
          _visible = true;
        });
      });
    });

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(param_homepage: 'Welcome Home')),
          (e) => false);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (_controller != null) {
      _controller.dispose();
      _controller = null;
    }
  }

  _getVideoBackground() {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
    );
  }

  _getBackgroundColor() {
    return Container(color: Colors.transparent //.withAlpha(120),
        );
  }

  _getContent() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _getVideoBackground(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```